# (Strong) Lower semicontinuity w.r.t. $L^\infty$ norm

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $B_1$ denote the unit ball in $\mathbb R^d$ and set $\mathcal K := \{\eta \in C_c^\infty(B_1): \eta \ge 0, \int \eta = 1,  \vert \nabla \eta \vert \le M \}$ where $M>0$ is a fixed real number (large enough). 
Consider the following functional 
$$\tag{1}
\mathcal K \ni \eta \mapsto \int_{B_1}\big\vert \langle x, \nabla \eta(x)\rangle \big\vert \, dx. 
$$
I am trying to understand its behaviour w.r.t. uniform topology on $\mathcal K$, i.e. the one induced by the $L^\infty$ norm.

> **Question.** Is the functional $(1)$ continuous (or, at least, lower semicontinuous) on the compact set $\mathcal K$?

I am puzzled... are there any general results I can apply? I was about to try to use directly the definition, i.e. take a sequence $\eta_n \to \eta$ uniformly; but do not know what to do now, I have no information a part the uniform bound on $\nabla \eta_n$... and I do not see how to apply Fatou's lemma.

Thanks.

EDIT: another try... Seems it is continuous w.r.t. $s-W^{1,1}$ topology... But I am not sure and I do not know how to use this piece of information.

Comment: Is it obvious that the set $\mathcal K$ is nonempty in any dimension? By Poincaré $\|\nabla u\|_1$ bounds $\|u\|_1$ from above up to a constant, and I don't know which is the optimal constant. Trying e.g. the function $1-|x|$ the constant seems to go to zero when $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, that is actually not a problem, in the sense that I wrote $\vert \nabla \eta \vert \le 1$ but I am actually interested only in a bound on the gradient... Let me edit the text so that it is clearer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is lower semicontinuous, but not continuous with respect to the uniform topology.

A good reference concerning lower semicontinuity in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ for functionals of the type
$$F(u)=\int_\Omega f(x,u(x),\nabla u(x))dx$$
is the book by Dacorogna, *Direct Methods in the Calculus of Variations*. In particular Corollary 3.22 apply to your case. As a general rule, in order to have weak-$W^{1,p}$ lower semicontinuity of these kind of functionals, the essential thing is that $f(x,s,\xi)$ must be convex in $\xi$. There are other assumptions on the semicontinuity and growth of $f$ etc., but they are usually verified for, say, $f$ continuous.

In your case the uniform convergence implies for any $p\geq 1$ the $L^p$ convergence which, together with the boundedness of the gradients in $L^p$,  is equivalent for $1<p<\infty$ to the weak-$W^{1,p}$ convergence (up to subsequences). Moreover $|\langle x,\xi\rangle|$ is convex in $\xi$, so you obtain the result. As noted in the comments, the lower semicontinuity result is still true in the weak*-$W^{1,\infty}$ topology. So we conclude if we can prove that up to subsequences $\eta_n\to \eta$ in this topology. But this is true by basically the same argument that proves the above result about weak convergence for $1<p<\infty$: by hypothesis $\eta_n\to \eta$ in $L^\infty$, and $\|\nabla \eta\|_\infty$ are bounded, so by Banach-Alaoglu they converge weakly* up to subsequences, and we are done.

Regarding the continuity, let us restrict to the case $d=1$, the general case being similar, and let us take functions in $W^{1,\infty}$ (the smooth case is obtained by approximation). Take for instance $\eta(x)=1-|x|$. The sequence $\eta_n$ is obtained with functions whose derivative in $(-1,0)$ oscillates between two values $a$ and $b$, and this happens on smaller and smaller scales as $n\to\infty$ (see picture which is zoomed in a point where $\eta'=1$; on $(0,1)$ the slopes are inverted).

$\hskip2in$ [image: Oscillating slopes]

To have a global average slope of $1$, the condition is $b=2-a$. If both $a$ and $b$ are positive then the integral is $\frac12|a|+\frac12|2-a|=1$, and the functional converges to the right thing along the sequence. But if you take $a<0$ (as in the picture) the integral becomes $\frac12|a|+\frac12|2-a|=1+|a|$, and thus along this sequence the functional has a value strictly larger than the value in the limit function $\eta$.

Instead if we take the strong $W^{1,1}$ topology you can check just by triangle inequalities that the functional is continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very precise answer. Dacorogna, of course! I should have thought to it before (unfortunately I am not an expert in calculus of variations). Thank you very much. I have only one small doubt: why boundedness of gradients imply w-$W^{1,1}$ convergence? I have always troubles with the exponent $p=1$ because I always dread finishing in $BV$... So, for sure if $\eta_n \to \eta$ strongly in $L^\infty$, then it holds also in $L^1$. Now how do we say that $\nabla \eta_n \rightharpoonup \nabla\eta$ weakly in $L^1$? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I try to reply by myself to my comment: actually, we do not care about w-$W^{1,1}$, we could stick to the more general $w^\star-W^{1,\infty}$ convergence. The Theorem from Dacorogna still applies (see Remark 3.25(ii) ibidem); furthermore, $\eta_n \to \eta$ (even) strongly in $L^\infty$, while for sure $\nabla \eta_n \rightharpoonup \nabla \eta$ in $w^\star-L^\infty$ by direct application of Banach-Alaouglu. Does this make sense? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes you are right! I don't even know why I spoke about $W^{1,1}$ in the first place...$W^{1,\infty}$ was what I had in mind in the beginning. You are right too about finishing in BV (I often fear this myself). In fact the remark I made holds only for $p>1$, by Kakutani and reflexivity. I'll edit my post later. Thanks!